# how to upload picture in asp.net using jquery and save it in folder

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to use jquery dialog to upload an image and save it in server folder 'images' and send the image path to the database.

Here's my fileupload control in asp which in displayed on jquery dialog ui

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="upl_Photo" runat="server" />
```

When i click 'Ok' button on my dialog button I need it to save the image in 'images' folder.

```
$(function () {
$(".dialog_Items").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    modal: true,
    show: 'fade',
    buttons: {
        'Add': function () {
           //save image in a server folder

            $.ajax({
                //send saved image path 

            });

            $(this).dialog('close');

        },
        'Cancel': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
    open: function (event) {
        $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:contains("Add")').addClass('addButton');
        $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:contains("Cancel")').addClass('cancelButton');
    }
});

$("#btn_Items").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".dialog_Items").dialog("open");
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

you can use ASP.Net fileupload control to upload multiple files....with ajax UpdatePAnel....once posted to server, saving files to disk and copying the paths is not so problamatic....

or else you can use uploadify - http://www.uploadify.com/